# How to see later-time behavior only of a system of ODEs in Matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, stability-in-odes

Let's say I coded up a model in Matlab, and the model is described by a set of ordinary differential equations that can be solved by the default `ode45` solver.  How can I see the model behavior for later time scales instead of starting at time $t = 0$?

I've tried the naïve thing: input time scale `tspan = [20 50]`, but that apparently just means that the model runs at time $t = 0$, for 30 seconds.

Comment: Can you specify the equations of the model? The Matlab script that you run?

Comment: How do your ODEs depend on time? Can't help much without details of the system. What are you actually trying to do?  You will need to specify valid initial conditions that correspond to time 20. If the only way to find these ICs is to integrate from 0 to 20 then you're out of luck unless your system has special characteristics (e.g., periodicity) or analytic solutions that can be leveraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runge-Kutta methods like Matlab's `ode45` do not conserve energy. In other words, computing the long-time behavior is very challenging due to the accumulation of numerical errors over the duration of the simulation. In some particular cases, other approaches are more successful than direct numerical integration. If the long-time behavior $t\to \infty$ is periodic (e.g. constant), then injecting a truncated Fourier series *Ansatz* in the equations and solving the system of equations satisfied by the coefficients may work fine. This approach is known as the [*harmonic balance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_balance) method.